# Replace query_posts with pre_get_posts

Tags: query-posts, pre-get-posts

I have a static front page that checks if the user is logged in, and if he/she is a number of x posts from a specific category is displayed. For that I was using this code:

```
query_posts('cat=2&showposts=5'.'&orderby=date&order=desc');
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
the_content();
endwhile;
```

Now I found out that's not right to use `query_post` and that I should use `pre_get_posts` instead. I've tried to do this but somehow my page breaks down saying that my server is configured incorrectly.

Comment: Please post your _exact_ error message and what you've tried. The above code btw shows nothing that could be used to check if the user is logged in.

Comment: I didn't said that the code above checks if the user is logged in. I have another code for that. This code just shows to the logged in users a a numbers of posts from a certain category. That's all . What I want is to convert the query_posts into pre_get_posts. I don't need a code to check if the user is logged in or smth.

Comment: and my error was from removing the above query_posts and inserting another code for pre_get_posts into functions.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the broken code it is hard to say, but your filter should look something like this:

```
function pregp_wpse_97354($qry) {
  if (is_front_page() && is_main_query() && is_user_logged_in()) {
    $qry->set('cat',2);
    $qry->set('posts_per_page',5);
    $qry->set('orderby','date');
    $qry->set('order','DESC');
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','pregp_wpse_97354');
```

You mentioned something about the user being logged in, which your code does not check for, but I threw that in. This will run before the theme templates load so if this is conditional on the user being logged in you need to include that check in the filter callback.

Comment: Thanks. I think this will do the work. Anyway what I was saying is that I have a static front page with a login form. If you are logged in or you log in on same page you see the posts that I was retrieving with that function.