# Pagination for Custom Post Type with Multiple Types

Tags: custom-post-types, navigation, custom-post-type-archives

The first page shows the first results however, mypages/page2 leads to a 404 error. The following code is inside archives-mypages.php

```
<?php
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query=null;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => array ( 'reports', 'results', 'reports-drop','reports-snap'),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'paged' => $paged,
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $wp_query -> have_posts() )
{
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
    ?>
    <a target="blank" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">The Link</a>
    <?php
    endwhile;
}
else
{
    echo 'no files found';
}?>

Page: <?php echo paginate_links(array(
          'base' => 'http://mywebsite.com/mypages/%_%',
          'format' => 'page/%#%',
          'current' => (get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1),
          'prev_next' => false,
          'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
          'mid_size' => 2,
          'type' => 'plain'
    ));?>

<?php
    //clear again
    $wp_query = null;
    //reset
    $wp_query = $temp;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the `$paged` parameter anywhere in that code. You need a line something like this:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

It really looks like you should be using a function hooked to `pre_get-posts` as [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/97358/21376) and as in [a lot of answer on the site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=pre_get_posts).