# How to use pre_get_posts?

Tags: pagination, pre-get-posts

I am having a problem with the custom category template pagination and i search and read that using pre_get_posts fix the pagination problem. I read the pre_get_posts information in the WordPress Codex but i didn't understand how to use it.

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'meta_key' => 'hmeromhnia_lhkshs',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'posts_per_page' => 9,
            'paged' => $paged
            );


// get results
query_posts( $args );?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

// The Loop

<?php endwhile;?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($wp_query->max_num_pages > 1) tie_pagenavi(); ?>

<?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>
```

This is the code i use for the query and the pagination doesn't work. I can't understand where and when to insert the pre_get_posts. Generally don't know how to use it.

Please help me!

Comment: Have you read our [topics for that tag](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pre-get-posts?sort=votes&pagesize=50)?

Comment: Yes i read them and i was searching and testing in my site for about 3 hours. It seems that there are different cases for pre_get_posts and pagination issues..

Comment: Then add your code to your question. _Be specific._

Comment: Here's [one solution](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4696/pagination-not-working-with-custom-loop) that comes up in the search.

Comment: @dalbaeb, i already tried this!

Comment: Try this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/97354/21376

Comment: @s_ha_dum, i tried to insert this code in the functions.php but nothing happened:

`function pregp_wpse_97354($qry) {
  if (is_category() ) {
    $qry->set('cat',88);
    $qry->set('posts_per_page',8);
 $qry->set('meta_key','hmeromhnia_lhkshs');
 $qry->set('orderby','meta_value_num');
    $qry->set('order','ASC');
 $qry->set('posts_per_page',9);
 $qry->set('paged',$paged);
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','pregp_wpse_97354');`

Comment: Is the file name `category.php`?

Comment: In the category template also i have this code:
`<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_key' => 'hmeromhnia_lhkshs',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
           'order' => 'ASC',
           'posts_per_page' => 9,
           'paged' => $paged );

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

<?php endwhile;?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($the_query->max_num_pages > 1) tie_pagenavi(); ?>

<?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>`

Comment: @s_ha_dum, No it is `category-expiresoon.php`

Comment: Could you please stop stuffing things in the comments and instead update your answer? :)

Answer (score 3):

Remove all query code from the template and just leave the default loop. In your example code you're overwriting the query in the template, in the code you pasted in the comments, you're running an entirely new query. These are both unnecessary when using `pre_get_posts`.

Put your `pre_get_posts` code in `functions.php`. You don't have to pass `$paged` or do anything fancy except set the specific parameters you want to modify, this code is running *before the query happens*:

```
function pregp_wpse_102658( $qry ) {
    if ( $qry->is_main_query() && $qry->is_category( 'expiresoon' ) ) {
        $qry->set('meta_key','hmeromhnia_lhkshs');
        $qry->set('orderby','meta_value_num');
        $qry->set('order','ASC');
        $qry->set('posts_per_page',9);
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','pregp_wpse_102658');
```

and then just use the plain vanilla loop in the template:

```
if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();  
        // The Loop
    endwhile;
endif;
```

If there is nothing else special about this particular category, you no longer need a category template specific to that one category, since the query modification now happens outside the template.

Comment: i inserted the code and now it doesn't display any of the posts.

Comment: are you sure you removed everything unnecessary from the template? are you sure meta key is correct and is associated to posts? are you sure category slug is correct?