# Same posts within a paginated page

Tags: loop, templates, pagination

I have a specific template that displays only posts from a category (350). When I paginate my posts, the posts stay the same. Below is some code that makes up this template. Any ideas how to correct this?

```
<?php if (is_front_page()) { ?>
    <?php get_template_part('home'); ?>
<?php } else { ?>   
    <?php 
    $et_ptemplate_settings = array();
    $et_ptemplate_settings = maybe_unserialize( get_post_meta($post->ID,'et_ptemplate_settings',true) );

    $fullwidth = isset( $et_ptemplate_settings['et_fullwidthpage'] ) ? (bool) $et_ptemplate_settings['et_fullwidthpage'] : false;

    $et_ptemplate_blogstyle = isset( $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_blogstyle'] ) ? (bool) $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_blogstyle'] : false;

    $et_ptemplate_showthumb = isset( $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_showthumb'] ) ? (bool) $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_showthumb'] : false;

    $blog_cats = isset( $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_blogcats'] ) ? (array) $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_blogcats'] : array();
    $et_ptemplate_blog_perpage = isset( $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_blog_perpage'] ) ? (int) $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_blog_perpage'] : 10;
    ?>

        <div id="content" class="clearfix<?php if($fullwidth) echo(' pagefull_width');?>">
            <div id="content-area"> 
                <div class="entry clearfix">
                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <?php query_posts('cat=350'); ?>

                    <h1 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                    <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<p><strong>'.esc_html__('Pages','Minimal').':</strong> ', 'after' => '</p>', 'next_or_number' => 'number')); ?>

                    <div id="et_pt_blog">
                        <?php $cat_query = ''; 
                        if ( !empty($blog_cats) ) $cat_query = '&cat=' . implode(",", $blog_cats);
                        else echo '<!-- blog category is not selected -->'; ?>
                        <?php 
                            $et_paged = is_front_page() ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : get_query_var( 'paged' );
                        ?>
                        <?php query_posts("showposts=$et_ptemplate_blog_perpage&paged=" . $et_paged . $cat_query); ?>
                        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                            <div class="et_pt_blogentry clearfix">
                                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                            </div> <!-- end .et_pt_blogentry -->

                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                            <div class="page-nav clearfix">
                                <?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(); }
                                else { ?>
                                     <?php get_template_part('includes/navigation'); ?>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div> <!-- end .entry -->
                        <?php else : ?>
                            <?php get_template_part('includes/no-results'); ?>
                        <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>

                    </div> <!-- end #et_pt_blog -->

                <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
                </div> <!-- end .entry -->

            </div> <!-- end #content-area -->   

    <?php if (!$fullwidth) get_sidebar(); ?>
        </div> <!-- end #content --> 

    <?php get_footer(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are running `query_posts` in the middle of the page, which, by the way you should nearly never do. That will overwrite the main query-- the `global` `$wp_query` object. Pagination should probably *appear* to work. The problem is that the original main query runs before your template loads and thus before the modified version of your query runs, and because of that the main query and the one that is being paginated are out of sync.

You probably need to use a filter on `pre_get_posts`, [something like this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/97358/21376), instead of running another query in the middle of the page. In your case you are going to need to pull in some information.

Here is a best guess at what you need (completely untested):

```
function pre_get_posts_wpse_104225($qry) {
  if (is_main_query() && !is_front_page()) {
    $et_ptemplate_blog_perpage = isset( $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_blog_perpage'] ) 
      ? (int) $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_blog_perpage'] 
      : 10;

    $blog_cats = isset( $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_blogcats'] ) 
      ? (array) $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_blogcats'] 
      : array();

    $cat_query = implode(",", $blog_cats);

    $qry->set('posts_per_page',$et_ptemplate_blog_perpage);
    $qry->set('category__in', $cat_query);
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','pre_get_posts_wpse_104225');
```

I am sure you would need more conditions that this-- `if (is_main_query() && !is_front_page()) {`-- but I can't tell exactly what else.